# Minimum number of circular segments.

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Let K be any natural number. Consider the unit square, and the circle of diameter 1 inside of the square. We then consider circular segments of area $\frac{1}{2K}$ and claim that there exists a constant $c$ such that $\#$(mutually disjoint circular segments of area $\frac{1}{2K}$)$\geq cK^{\frac{1}{3}}$. 
Why is this correct? I tried explaining to myself by geometry but not with the best of results. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about the unit square, it's irrelevant.

Let K be a positive real. The maximum area of disjoint segments arises if the segments bound a polygon inscribed in the circle, and since the areas of a set of segments for a given K are equal that polygon is regular.

Let $n$ be the number of segments. Let $\theta$ be the angle subtended at the centre of the circle by each segment, so $\theta = 2\pi/n$.

The area of a segment is $\pi r^2/n - \frac{1}{2}r^2 \sin\theta$; $r = \frac{1}{2}$, so

$\frac{1}{2K} = \pi /4n - \sin\theta / 8$
$\frac{4}{K} = 2\pi /n - \sin\theta$
$\frac{4}{K} = \theta - \sin\theta$

Now $\sin \theta = \theta - \theta^3/3! + \theta^5/5! - ...$

For small $\theta$ (large $n$) we can ignore the 3rd & subsequent terms. So

$$\begin{align}
\frac{4}{K} & \approx \theta^3/6\\  
\frac{24}{K} & \approx \theta^3\\   
\left(\frac{24}{K}\right)^\frac{1}{3} & \approx \theta = 2\pi/n\\   
\left(\frac{K}{24}\right)^\frac{1}{3} & \approx n / 2\pi\\   
n & \approx 2\pi\left(\frac{K}{24}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\\   
n & \approx \left(\frac{2\pi}{24^\frac{1}{3}}\right) K^\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

So $n$ is proportional to $K^\frac{1}{3}$ for sufficiently large $n$. I'll let you clean up the fine details relating to bounds. :)

Comment: You might want to use `\sin` instead of `sin` to make the function name upright ($\sin$ vs. $sin$). Also use `\left(` and `\right)` to make parentheses automatically grow to fit their contents (eg. fractions: $\left(\frac 12\right)$ vs. $(\frac 12)$).

Comment: @CiaPan: Thanks! As you can tell, my LaTeX skills are rudimentary. I _do_ know about `\sin, \left( and \right)` I just forget to use them. :)

Comment: I was sure the problem could be transfered to polygons, but it wasnt clear to me, how to bring regular polygons in. Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: @möbiusstripper: My pleasure! I _was_ just going to drop a few hints in the comments, but it's such a cute problem that I couldn't resist providing a (mostly) complete answer. :)